# Symbolic manipulation over non-numeric types

Tags: python, sympy

I'm interested in a python library that permits symbolic manipulation where the symbols and can be unknowns of an arbitrary type.

This is the code that I *want* to write:

```
>>> myexpression = symbol("foo") == "bar"
>>> print myexpression
foo == "bar"
>>> print myexpression(foo="quux")
False
>>> myexpression.or_(True)
True
```

Or some rough approximation of that.  It doesn't actually even need to be that clever, I'd be happy enough having to call a lot of extra introspection methods to get something like the above (for instance, even if the logical tautology is not directly simplified)

My first instinct was to look at [sympy](http://sympy.org/), but it seems that library makes the strong assumption that symbolic variables must be numbers; and I'd like to at least operate on sequences and sets:

```
>>> myexpression = sympy.Eq(sympy.Symbol("foo"), 5)
>>> myexpression
foo == 5
>>> myexpression = sympy.Eq(sympy.Symbol("foo"), "bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: 'bar'
```

Is there a way to get sympy to understand non-numeric variables, or another library that can do similar things?

Comment: What about using one or more dictionaries with `sympy.Symbol` objects as keys?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how well it fits the uses you have in mind, but the `nltk` (Natural Language Toolkit) has modules for symbolic manipulation, including first order logic, typed lambda calculus, and a theorem prover. Take a look at [this howto](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/inference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could you just map everything into a Sympy symbol? For instance, in your last expression:
sympy.Eq(sympy.Symbol("foo"), sympy.Symbol("bar")). Or do you mean you actually want to write logical statements about set relationships?

Comment: I do want to write logical statements; For instance, I'd like to be able to express `X & (Y | Z)`, and be able to distribute the intersection `(X & Y) | (X & Z)`, Or visa versa; in the hope of picking one to actually execute (based on some cost considering the distribution of elements in `X`, `Y` and `Z`.)

Answer (score 0):

Boolean logic is in SymPy although not as easily expressible as it should be. Its definitely there though.

```
In [1]: x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
In [2]: A = Eq(x,y)
In [3]: A
Out[3]: x = y

In [4]: B = Gt(y,z)
In [5]: And(A,B)
Out[5]: x = y ∧ y > z

In [6]: C = Gt(x,z)
In [7]: And(A, Or(B,C))
Out[7]: x = y ∧ (y > z ∨ x > z)
```

I'm not aware of many methods to simplify these expressions. This is the sort of thing that would be easy to do if there was interest though.

Comment: Well what I'm really interested in is using *knowns* with types other than scalars.  For example, I would like to manipulate expressions/equations where the variables are sets.  Untyped variables are not really what I'm after.